# how to change the size of an exposed filter autocomplete form?

Tags: views, ajax

the source shows:

```
<input id="edit-field-location-taxonomize-terms-tid" class="form-text form-autocomplete ctools-auto-submit-processed" type="text" maxlength="128" size="60" value="Germany" name="field_location_taxonomize_terms_tid" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

tried `hook_form_alter` but didn't find `size` or `maxlength` using `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>');`

also

```
function modulename_element_info() {
  $types['textfield'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#autocomplete_path' => FALSE,
    '#process' => array('ajax_process_form'),
    '#theme' => 'textfield',
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );
}
```

didn't work and don't know if/how i can change the size with css.

any help is appreciated. thanks a lot!

Comment: According to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#size, the default `#size` and `#maxlength` for a textfield are `60` and `128` and thus wouldn't necessarily be found in the form, but you can certainly set them there in that `form_alter()`....

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue in the Claro theme to reduce the exposed filter size but until then you can use this. Replace MYMODULE, MYVIEWID, and MYBLOCK. Haven't test this but it should work. I know its a lot of code for a small change. You could also do this with CSS. Oh you also have the change `uid` in the form variable.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_state->getStorage()) {
     $storage = $form_state->getStorage();
     if ($storage['view'] {
       if ($storage['view']->id() == 'MYVIEWID' && $storage['display']['id'] == 'MYBLOCK') {
         // Reduce the size of the input.
         $form['uid']['#size'] = 20;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

With CSS. Change `#EXPOSEDFILTERID`. I chose `data-drupal-selector` because after submitting the form, the ID changes. You should also change `uid`.

```
#EXPOSEDFILTERID input[data-drupal-selector="edit-uid"]{
  width:150px;
}
```